# Apache Mina: Get local port to which remote client connected

Tags: java, sockets, apache-mina

If I have a server listening on ports 80 and 8080 as configured below, how would I be able to identify which local port a client connected to when i get a message?

```
acceptor = new NioSocketAcceptor();
acceptor.setHandler(new MyConnectionHandler());
Set<SocketAddress> addresses = new HashSet<SocketAddress>();
addresses.add(new InetSocketAddress(host, 80));
addresses.add(new InetSocketAddress(host, 8080));
acceptor.bind(addresses);
```

The handler's *messageReceived* I want to know which local port the client connected to, not the client's remote port.

```
@Override
public void messageReceived(IoSession session, Object message) throws Exception {
    log.info("Incomming: {}", session.getRemoteAddress().toString());
```

Which method should I use to access the port which should be 80 or 8080? The log statement would print something like this:

```
    Incomming: /219.182.172.12:37921
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`session.getLocalAddress()`](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/apache/http/nio/reactor/IOSession.html#getLocalAddress)

Comment: Yay, this works! I had tried session.getServiceAddress() but its kind of a gotcha since it only returns the first port in the set which in my case was always 80